# No consigo cambiar rol mediante select

Tags: php, mysql

MI EJERCICIO:

En mi web hay 2 tipos de usuarios ( 1= Entrenador, 2= Jugador), si entras como rol Entrenador tienes un partador para hacer las convocatorias para los partidos, y cuando el usuario de turno entre con rol Jugador en el partado convocatorias vera un listado de los jugadores Convocados.

MI IDEA:

Había pensado en crear una tabla con todos los jugadores y cada uno de ellos tenga un select en el cual pueda elegir entre (1 = Convocado, 2= No convocado) y así, dependiendo de la elección, en la pagina que ven los Jugadores, solo aparezcan los elegidos con el rol (1= convocado)

Tengo en la base de datos una tabla llamada USER, en la cual hay una columna llamada idSeleccion, y otra tabla llamada SELECCIÓN, la cual contiene las columnas idSeleccion (relacionada con la de la otra tabla de mismo nombre) y rolC, las cuales contienen los datos 1 y 2, y Convocado y No convocado respectivamente.

El problema es que no consigo que el numero de la tabla idSeleccion cambie de 2(Siempre creo a usuarios con rolC=2) a 1.

Agradecería enormemente cualquier tipo de ayuda. A continuaciuon os dejo mi codigo. Un saludo

MI CODIGO:

CONVOCATORIAS.PHP (LA QUE VE EL ENTRENADOR).

```
<?php
include("../includes/_db.php");

$usuarios = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE rol = '2'";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $usuarios);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Jugadores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/MyCluB/css/convocatorias.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
        rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <form action="../includes/_functions.php" method="post">
        <div>
            <table class="tabla" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Dorsal</th>
                        <th>Posicion</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Convocar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['dorsal']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['posicion']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['nombre']?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['apellidos']?></td>
                        <td for="idSeleccion">
                            <select name="idSeleccion" id="idSeleccion">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <h5 class="centrar">// 1: Convocado // 2: No convocado //</h5>
        <div class="botones">
            <input type="submit" value="REALIZAR" class="anadir">
            <button onclick="window.location.href='../entrenador/dashboardEnt.php'" class="return">VOLVER</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="convocar">
                        <input type="hidden" name="idSeleccion" value="<?php echo $row['rolC'];?>">
                    </div>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5ceb5918c8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

_FUNCTIONS.PHP

```
<?php

require_once ("_db.php");

if (isset($_POST['accion'])){ 
    switch ($_POST['accion']){
        //casos de registros;
            case 'convocar';
            convocar();
            break;
        }
    }

function convocar() {
    $conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myclub");
    extract($_POST);
    $consulta="UPDATE user SET idSeleccion = '$idSeleccion' WHERE id = '$id'";

    mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    header('Location: ../entrenador/convocatoriasEnt.php');
}
```

MI BBDD:

TABLA USER
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TABLA SELECCION
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

DISEÑO
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problema parece estar en que `$id` no obtiene ningún valor, por lo que podrías poner un campo oculto para que desde el formulario mande la ID del user y esta sea obtenida en tu _FUNCTIONS.PHP y entonces el update se pueda hacer correctamente